# Creating a new Transport for "network" backup

Tags: libgit2

I'm working on a 'cloudy' S3-based research project in the secure storage area. I'd like to utilize libgit2 for versioning within my local clients and believe that creating a new transport might be the best solution. This would keep a fully-compatible fallback local git history (as compared to new odb or refdb backends).

When looking at the API, it seems as if the upload push and download packfile functionality would be critical. To toy around with the problem I'd really like to write a S3-transport (backend). While I do not believe that this could ever be race-free (due to S3's eventual consistency) but this should show most of the possible problems.

Currently I'm not sure how to produce the packfiles from the remote storage. With git_packbuilder_insert I could add all the needed OIDs, but where is the actual data retrieved from? Is this retreived from the repository (which is referenced when using packbuilder_new)? If so am I supposed to write a new transport as well as a corresponding repository type for that transport?

The other question is, if I should document my findings (I hope to get the funding for spending some days to weeks on implementing this) or is this too rare a use-case to be worth documenting?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make it possible for a user to do the equivalent of 'git push s3://whatever' to back up the files? If you're after a backup system, libgit2 (or git itself) would likely only ever be able to provide a bit of structure for versioning, but you still need to write all the logic for the backup itself.

Comment: @CarlosMartínNieto: yes. I want to use libgit2 for providing the versioning, tagging, etc. bits (so I wouldn't have to write them myself). This is part of a larger project.

The final backend would be something propietary (I'm trying to convince the company to do otherwise, but don't have too much hope), but I'd want to do a proof-of-concept (which would be S3) that could be OSS if anyone wants the code.

Answer (score 1):

S3 doesn't speak the smart protocol or emit packfiles for you, which means that you would have to build some sort of transport layer that takes Git objects stored in S3 and hand them over to libgit2 in some manner that it can consume.

This is *exactly* what the purpose of the ODB layer is.  If you created an ODB that read from and wrote to S3, then you would be able to create a `git_repository` from that backend store.  Once you did that, you could then provide the necessary mechanisms to clone it locally.

Or if you wanted a single `git_repository` that was backed by both a file and S3, then you could create a tee-style ODB layer that would write to both one of the local filesystem ODB drivers and the S3 ODB.

But unless I misunderstand your motivation, creating a custom transport will not yield the results you desire.

Comment: okay, I'll need to check the documentation again. I thought that the ODB would be used for 'local' storage only (i.e. .git/objects). If I provide a custom (i.e. S3-based) ODB backend that the objectdb part of .git would disappear and offline operaton would not work anymore. The reasoning for using a custom transport was that this would still allow offline operation and would keep the work directory git compatible.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do; but the ODB would only work when you were online, just like the transport would only work when you're online?  You would surely need two ODBs, one for the local store (`.git/objects`) that was always-on, one for the remote...?

Comment: Background: I'm involved with a secure storage ``cloudy'' solution which offers a Key/Value-Interface. Now I wanted to add software which should allow for periodic backup from a server (normal data directory) to the cloud-backed backup server.

As I need to create versions of the server-side directory, store it's history, etc. I thought about utilizing libgit2 for all this. First of all, is this an stupid idea?

I did get the documentation wrong -- so I could use 2 ODBs within the repository: one for the local storage (.git) and one for the remote backup storage?

Thanks for your effort!